# Call custom function from Joomla 4 user controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, joomla, joomla4

I am trying to access function of custom class from user component controller file, UserController.php file.

My custom class is defined in custom file at root level.

To access class, I have been trying to add file path manually in UserController but it is not working and getting an error like class not found,

`require_once(JPATH_ROOT . '/custom_file.php');`

I have also define namespace in my custom_file.php and add as use statement in UserController, but it also not working and getting error like class not found

custom_file.php:

```
namespace custom_class;

class custom_class{
   
   function abcd(){
   }
}
```

UserController.php

```
use custom_class;

class UserController extends BaseController
{

}
```

Can someone suggest how can i call function abcd() into my UserController.php file

Comment: The fully qualified class name of your custom class is `custom_function\custom_function` (NB a class is not a function - you should probably rename it, otherwise this is going to be confusing).  In your calling class (`UserController`) you already have a `use custom_function` statement, which means you should be able to instantiate an instance of your custom class with `$myclass = new custom_function\custom_function()` and then call `$myclass->abcd()`

Comment: Rob, thank you for response,
I have updated my question as per your suggestion, also I have added,
$myclass = new custom_class\abcd();    
in my controller function, but it return an error as not found.

Comment: That's not the name of your class, though.  You need `$myclass = new custom_class\custom_class()` to create an object of your custom class, then you can call the `abcd()` method on it with `$myclass->abcd()`

Comment: It still says custom_class\custom_class not found

Comment: Any idea how can I trigger function without use statement?

Comment: If your class is still not found, that means your file has not been processed.  Did you get an error from your `require_once` statement?

Comment: You don't need the `use` statement - that's just a convenient reference to the namespaces you intend to use in the following code.  You don't need it if you prefix with a backslash to refer to the global namespace, ie `$myclass = new \custom_class\custom_class();`

Comment: Yes, with the statement require_once I am not getting an error,  but after define class like, $myclass = new \custom_class\custom_class(); or $myclass = new custom_class(); I am getting an error. Also, I like to trigger custom_class without namespace.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're requiring `custom_file.php` before you're attempting to call `$myclass = new \custom_class\custom_class();`?

Comment: yes, I have included file before initiate class.
require_once(JPATH_ROOT . '/custom_file.php');
$myclass = new \custom_class\custom_class();

Comment: I created `custom_file.php` with the content you have shown, used `require_once` to include it, and called `$myclass = new \custom_class\custom_class();` without error.  Sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem.  Perhaps it is due to the version of PHP you are using, or something else in the files that is interfering with those definitions (you do have `<?php` at the top of `custom_file.php`, right?)

Comment: Yes, I am using <?php at top of custom_file.php and I have PHP 8.0 and Joomla 4.2.5 Version.